# gsap animation plays only once when I put it inside angular ngOnInit function

Tags: angular, gsap, ngoninit

I have an angular 7 project and imported Gsap library. I want an animation to be played every time I navigate to a page so I've implemented the gsap animation inside ngOnInit, but the animation plays only for the first time I visit the page and in the next visits there is no animation. I've created a callback to log a message when the animation completes and every time I navigate to the page I can see the complete message is logged in the console but there is no animation. 
here is my ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { TweenMax } from "gsap";
@Component({
  selector: "app-list",
  templateUrl: "list.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["list.page.scss"]
})
export class ListPage implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    TweenMax.to("#myTarget", 1, {
      y: -50,
      onComplete: function() {
        console.log("animation completed");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

thanks for help!

Comment: it makes no difference, I get the complete log message but animation plays only once

Comment: `TweenMax` call on every route or call only `list page`?. || try to add this code on appComponent and call on every route change

Comment: the animation is specific to listPage. my problem is that the gsap animation gets called and the complete message gets fired but the animation does not play visually.

Comment: can you create `stackblitz` for you problem.?

Answer (score 1):

actually, my code was working correctly!
the problem source was having two identical ids #myTarget in the homePage and listPage and when navigating between these two pages the gsap was confused with 2 unique ids. so I changed the id to class and problem solved